# npm lite-server doesn't recognize changes in css

Tags: angularjs, npm, livereload, node-sass, npm-install

I am building the angular 2 tour of heroes tutorial application. I am compiling my sass to generate the css but the lite-server doesn't recognize this change and hence doesn't refresh the browser. Changes to the .ts files are recognized as expected and the browser refreshes

My folder structure is like this:

```
-app (contains .ts and .sass files)
-public (contains the compiled .js and .css files)
index.html
```

Please see the package.json below.

```
  {
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf public/*",
    "build:sass": "node-sass --source-map public/ app/ -o public/",
    "build:ts": "tsc",
    "watch:sass": "nodemon -e scss -w app/ -x 'npm run build:sass'",
    "watch:ts": "nodemon -e ts -w app/ -x 'npm run build:ts'",
    "build": "npm run build:ts && npm run build:sass",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "watch": "concurrent \"npm run watch:sass\" \"npm run watch:ts\" \"npm run lite\""
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

Could you please tell me what the issue is? Once weird thing that I noticed was when the lite-server started, the .css file gets the HTTP 304 code and everything else under the public folder gets 200

```
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:55 304 GET /./index.html (Unknown - 8ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:55 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js (Unknown - 12ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:55 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js (Unknown - 11ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:55 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js (Unknown - 11ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:55 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js (Unknown - 11ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:56 200 GET /public/main/boot.js (Unknown - 253ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:56 200 GET /public/main/app.component.js (Unknown - 48ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:56 200 GET /public/hero/hero-detail.component.js (Unknown - 39ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:56 200 GET /public/hero/hero.service.js (Unknown - 39ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:56 200 GET /public/hero/mock-heroes.js (Unknown - 118ms)
[2] 16.01.09 03:43:56 304 GET /public/main/app.css (Unknown - 14ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `lite-server`'s [known issue](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#known-issues):

> CSS with Angular 2 is embedded thus even though BrowserSync detects the file change to CSS, it does not inject the file via sockets. As a workaround, `injectChanges` defaults to `false`